# Writing callbacks for a wizard?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm building a custom wizard in knockout that dynamically loads knockout components during each "step" of the wizard. I've managed to get all of this working without much hassle, and it seems to work pretty well.

However, I'm wanting to implement some callbacks within the wizard when certain events happen. For example, before and after navigation.

Currently, one of my navigation functions looks like this:

```
this.goNext = function () {
    if (!this.canGoNext()) return;

    this.currentStep(this.pages()[this.currentIndex() + 1]);
    this.loadPage();
}
```

I would like to build 2 callback functions called `beforePageChange` and `onPageChange`.

My general assumption is that `beforePageChange` would pass in a couple parameters, notably the current page and the next page. However, I also want it to be able to be observed from any other class utilization the wizard.

For example, on my parent page I would have something like:

```
this.wizard = Site.loadWizard(arguments);
this.wizard.beforePageChange(function(options) {
    if (!options.currentPage.complete) return false;

    // do stuff
    return true;
});
```

In turn the wizard would execute its navigation commands and trigger the appropriate callbacks.

I feel like there's something I'm just fundamentally missing here.

**Edit**

My current version works as follows:

In the wizard:

```
this.canChangePage = ko.obserable(true);
this.beforePageChange = function (options) {

};

this.beforePageChangeHandler = function (options) {
    this.beforePageChange(options);
    // do stuff
    return true;
};

this.onPageChange = function (options) {

};

this.onPageChangeHandler = function (options) {
    this.onPageChange(options);
    //do stuff
    return true;
}
```

On the page implementing the wizard:

```
    this.wizard = Site.loadComponent(params, function () {
    this.wizard.beforePageChange = function (options) {
        this.canChangePage(false);
    };
}.bind(this));
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to implement this, or if this is the best solution.

Comment: You can subscribe to "beforeChange" events in observables. I'm pretty sure you can build your intended functionality on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) described in their comment (I think):

Since you already have access to the `wizard` instance, you can subscribe to its `currentStep` observable. To get notifications before it changes, you pass a third parameter: `"beforeChange"`. (The second is the `this` context).

```js
var Wizard = function() {
   this.currentStep = ko.observable(0); 
}

Wizard.prototype.next = function() {
   this.currentStep(this.currentStep() + 1); 
}

Wizard.prototype.prev = function() {
   this.currentStep(this.currentStep() - 1); 
}

var Page = function() {
  this.wizard = new Wizard();
  
  this.wizard.currentStep.subscribe(function(oldStep) {
     console.log("Page work before step change from step", oldStep);
  }, this, "beforeChange");  
  
  this.wizard.currentStep.subscribe(function(newStep) {
     console.log("Page work after step change to", newStep);
  });
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new Page());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with:wizard">
  <button data-bind="click: prev">back</button>
  <span data-bind="text: currentStep"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: next">next</button>
  
</div>
```